# Date between two values - Lavarel SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, date, difference

I have a structure table like this : `Start_date`  `End_date`

Now with **today's date**, I should go and get all the data including from `Start_Date` and `End_Date`, what can I do?

I tried with

```
SELECT * 
FROM text 
WHERE Start_date BETWEEN '2021-10-10' AND '2021-10-08' 
OR End_date BETWEEN '2021-10-08' AND '2021-10-10
```

but to no avail ...

Comment: Please add sample data to make it clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I need to select all fields consisting of two dates start_date and end_date

dates are added in this format 2021-10-10 (yyyy/mm/dd)

Comment: @JDPinko please  edit your question and add table description ,some data in insert format and your expected result based in the data you will provide

Comment: do you need a laravel eloquent or MySQL query?

Comment: "but to no avail" doesn't tell us much. Do you get an error? If so what error. Do you get unexpected results? If so what are the results, and what did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`whereBetween`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-wherebetween) method in Laravel will determine if an items value is between the given range.

```
$start = '2021-10-08';
$end = '2021-10-10';

Text::whereBetween('start_date', [$start, $end])
      ->whereBetween('end_date', [$start, $end])
      ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. if you just want to get data from start to end date you can use this eloquent Code

```
$start_date = "2020-10-20";
$end_date = "2021-10-20";
Text::where(function ($wh) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
   $wh->whereBetween('Start_date', [$start_date, $end_date])->orwhereBetween('End_date', [$start_date, $end_date]);
})->get();
```

here is a raw query from the above eloquent code

```
select * from `users` where (`Start_date` between '2020-10-20' and '2021-10-20' or `End_date` between '2020-10-20' and '2021-10-20')
```

2. if you want to find data from start to end date including today's date you can you this eloquent Code

```
$start_date = "2020-10-20";
$end_date = "2021-10-20";
Text::where(function ($wh) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
   $today_date = date('Y-m-d');
   $wh->where(function ($or_where) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
      $or_where->whereBetween('Start_date', [$start_date, $end_date])
               ->orwhereBetween('End_date', [$start_date, $end_date]);
            })->orwhereRAW("('{$today_date}' between `Start_date` and `End_date`)");
})->get();
```

here is a raw query from the above eloquent code

```
select * from `text` where ((`Start_date` between '2020-10-20' and '2021-10-20' or `End_date` between '2020-10-20' and '2021-10-20') or ('2021-10-09' between `Start_date` and `End_date`))
```